# Automatically log out user when they leave the iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I have an in-house app which is used by staff but the chances are the device it is used on could become consumer facing. With that in mind I want to ensure that should the staff forget to logout when they switch apps or just reopen the app that I have a command in there to effectively log them out.

After researching I think the best way for me would be to use:

```
optional func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)
```

and then force the app to go to the login page or the reverse so that when app enters background it forces the app to the logout URL.

Which do you think would be best and how can I use that command to then add in the chosen URL as described above?

Comment: _"app enters background it forces the app to the logout URL"_ This seems like bad UX. The first one where you display the login page on returning from background seems fine. It is important that the user is able to resume his work where he left off after logging in again.

Answer (score 0):

So, while I agree with @Rakesha-Shastri in that ""app enters background it forces the app to the logout URL" This seems like bad UX. The first one where you display the login page on returning from background seems fine. It is important that the user is able to resume his work where he left off after logging in again," there does need to be a way, in-case a user is gone too long, that the credentials have passed. It seems in your case, that every time the user LEAVES or CLOSES the app, you want this to be unauthenticated. What if the user gets a phone call? Should it do that? You may want to use `Timer`, of say some period of time, 2-5 minutes maybe.

Any who, what you can do is force the user to have to RESTART the app, by either presenting a controller that has NO CAPABILITY of going anywhere, therefore forcing a restart, or providing a button that sends them to a login screen you have implemented.

**Note:**

I would definitely indicate to the user, "due to purposes of security, each time you exit the app, it requires an authentication to re-access. Please log back in". Then provide a button to the login screen.

As you did not provide code, and I'm not going to do this for you, a direction to take this would be to utilize `optional func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)` alongside with getting the current UIViewController. I would google how to do that. Then from there, you can create a new UIViewController that presents this button back to the login screen.